# Do two consecutive DirectX 12 Dispatch() calls run sequentially or concurrently on the GPU?

Tags: c++, compute-shader, directx-12

When running two `Dispatch()` calls consecutively, like:

```
m_computeCommandList->Dispatch(111, 1, 1);
m_computeCommandList->Dispatch(555, 1, 1);
```

Is it guaranteed that the second `Dispatch()` will run after the first `Dispatch()` on the GPU?  Or, could they run concurrently on the GPU?

Just to clarify, there is no more C++ code in between those two `Dispatch()` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in other graphics API, when you execute command calls on CPU side it leads to putting these commands to a command queue. It guarantees that **commands will be processed in the order of queue, First-In-First-Out**.

However, **on GPU everything becomes massive parallel and concurrent**. We can't know on what processing unit the actual execution will be scheduled, or what threads from what `Dispatch` will be finished earlier. Typically it's not a problem if there are no resources (buffers, textures) shared between invocations, and we need to synchronize only the end of frame.

If there is resource sharing, there is a possibility of some memory conflicts ("write-read", "write-write" or "read-write"). Here we need to use [resource barriers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/using-resource-barriers-to-synchronize-resource-states-in-direct3d-12) that allow us to organize access to these resources. Using different options for barriers you can reach the consecutive execution of different `Dispatch` calls.

> For example, a transition from D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS to D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_NON_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE|D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE will wait for ALL preceding Graphics and Compute shader execution to complete, and block ALL subsequent Graphics and Compute shader execution.

[Enhanced barriers](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/D3D12EnhancedBarriers.html) in DirectX 12 allow you to get fine-tuned control on resource and execution synchronization.

Comment: your answer let me find that Unordered access view (UAV) barrier is the solution to my problem